# Javascript: Clean way to check an ovject value (And return false if the value doesn't exist)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I've got an object containing multiple objects, like this:

```
let data = {
    hello: {
        melon: {
           yes: true
        }
    }
}
```

Here I want to check if "yes" is equal to true. The problem being that the "data" object could contain nothing, and the "hello" object could contain nothing, and it goes on. Here's what I did:

```
if(data.hello && && data.hello.melon && data.hello.melon.yes && data.hello.melon.yes === true){...}
```

Is there a way to make this condition cleaner?

Comment: Consider [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: ----------
If you use ES6 there is [optional chaining][1] so you can do 

    const isTrue = data?.hello?.melon?.yes
This will return `undefined` which is translated to `false` in conditional statement. But if you really need `boolean` use double exclamation mark `!!` to convert it to `boolean`, so full code will look like

        const isTrue = !!data?.hello?.melon?.yes



  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ES2020 there is cool feature called [optional chaining](https://v8.dev/features/optional-chaining), so you can use it:

```
let foo = data?.hello?.melon?.yes
```

Also you can combine it with feature called [nulish coalescing](https://v8.dev/features/nullish-coalescing) to set default value:

```
let foo = data?.hello?.melon?.yes ?? 'default value'
```

So the condition will look like:

if (data?.hello?.melon?.yes === true)